# Can I snap bones only to bones in edit mode?

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, snapping

I'm trying to edit a rig with the mesh visible. When I use snapping, the bones want to snap to the mesh (which figures because they're inside it, so the mesh verts are in front of the bones). Is there a way to limit snapping only to the other bones of the armature, ignoring the mesh?

Comment: I don't suppose you can hide the mesh?

Comment: Well I'm rigging the mesh, so it's useful to be able to see it when I'm editing the bones. The XRay trick works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to enable X-Ray mode, allowing you to see and snap to your bones through your mesh without hiding it. It can also be found in the top-right of the viewport, near the buttons for viewport shading. It's the one that looks like two squares overlaying each other, roughly in the middle of the buttons:

[image: Toggle X-Ray button located in upper right of viewport]

Then make sure your Snap To setting is set to Vertex using the menu in the top-center of the viewport area. This will ensure the ends of bones will properly snap into the same place, rather than on the surface of another end point. Snap With doesn't seem to affect it from my testing, so I just put it back on the default of Closest.

[image: Snapping settings]

With X-Ray disabled (but bones set to always visible on top), the bone here snaps to the surface of this character's arm:

[image: Snapping without X-Ray]

But with X-Ray enabled, the bone ends snap to each other:

[image: Snapping with X-Ray]

Also as a bit of a side note: if you have the NVIDIA GeForce Experience overlay enabled, the default hotkey for that is also <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, so you might want to change it or disable it so toggling X-Ray on and off frequently doesn't keep opening the overlay.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Chromarict answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252633/35559) , if you still unable to snap even in XRay mode, you might need to toggle *Include Non-Edited* to off.

[image]